# how to acquire a certain sound which lack in my mother tongue?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

In my mother language, there is a lack of the N sound as an initial consonant. Every time when I say English words like **nature**, **new**, it will naturally or unconsciously be pronounced as **lature**, **lew**.

What is worse is that when I speak other languages, the same issue occurs.

Is there some study in phonetics on how to solve my problem?

Comment: There is only one way: **practice**. Does /n/ exist at all in your native language, or is it only initially it doesn’t occur (like in many southern Chinese languages)? It can be difficult to learn to produce a sound syllable-initially that only exists in syllable-final position in your own language – for example, many English speakers find it hard to pronounce initial /ŋ/ or /ts/ – but it’s not impossible. It just takes practice.